# Is there a way to use Javascript to add to previous scripts?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdfmake

**Is there a way to use Javascript to add to previous scripts?**
I am using the library pdfmake, which is what I am basing my question on, so if there is a separate way to do what I want to do using the library (or anything else really), please tell me. I didn't find a way on the website, but if there are other helpful resources, feel free to share.

---

I have scoured google for an answer for this, and could not find one, so I am using this a last resort, not a first resort.
I am trying to add to a PDF for a resume builder, but for it to work, I need to continuously add to the PDF using new added information. Is it possible to have a function add script to a previous function, or do I need another way to do this?

---

Comment: Functions cannot be altered once they're instantiated. You can add one or more wrapper functions around an existing function to fool with inputs and the return value, but you cannot change what the function does.

Comment: @Pointy: But functions can be redefined. So depending on the use-case it is as good as altering them.

Comment: @slebetman if the function you want to change is a PDF generator, doing so by replacing it with your own PDF generator might be a little challenging :)

Comment: @Pointy: Yes, that's why I said depending on the use-case. A simple function is easy to rename and wrap around. A method is a bit more complicated because you have to be careful with `this`. A method that uses closures to reference "private" variables is almost impossible to replace.

Answer (score 1):

For making a function execute code and then make it execute more code, you could have an array of functions and make the main function execute them. For example:

```
var list_of_functions = [function a(param){"code here"}, function b(param){"code here"}];
function main(){
    for(i in list_of_functions){
        list_of_functions[i](param);
    }
}
list_of_functions.push(function c(param){"new code")});
```